# subquery uses ungrouped column "i.date_time" from outer query

Tags: sql, subquery

I have 2 tables: `item_status_log` and `items` with the following structure:

```
items(itemid, status, ordertype)

item_status_log(itemid, date_time, new_status, old_status)
```

Basically, when the `status` is changed in my program, a record is logged in the `item_status_log` with the `old_status`, the `new_status`, and the `date_time`.

What I want is to be able to view a table of items grouped by the date they were updated. I have the following sql which works perfectly:

```
select 
    to_char(date_time, 'MM-DD-YYYY') as "Shipment Date", 
    count(*) as "TOTAL Items"
from item_status_log i 
where old_status = 'ONORDER' 
group by "Shipment Date" 
order by "Shipment Date" desc
```

this gives me:

```
Shipment Date  |   TOTAL Items
------------------------------
09/02/2014     |   4
09/01/2014     |   23
```

However, I want to add 2 columns to the above table, which breaks down how many of the items have a status in the items table of 'INVENTORY' and 'ORDER'.

I'm looking for this:

```
 Shipment Date  |   TOTAL Items  |  Inventory   |  Ordered 
 ---------------------------------------------------------
 09/02/2014     |   4            |        3     |      1
 09/01/2014     |   23           |       20     |      3
```

Here is what I have tried, but got the '*subquery uses ungrouped column "i.date_time" from the outer query*' error:

```
select 
    to_char(date_time, 'MM-DD-YYYY') as "Shipment Date", 
    count(*) as "TOTAL Items",
    (select count(*) 
     from item_status_log t 
     where date(t.date_time) = date(i.date_time) and 
     itemid in (
         select itemid 
         from items 
         where ordertype = 'ORDER'
    )) as "Customer",
    (select count(*) 
     from item_status_log t 
     where date(t.date_time) = date(i.date_time) and 
     itemid in (
         select itemid 
         from items 
         where  ordertype = 'INVENTORY'
    )) as "Inventory"
from item_status_log i 
where old_status = 'ONORDER' 
group by "Shipment Date" 
order by "Shipment Date" desc
```

Comment: use count(1) not count(*) not necessary to check all columns

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you just need conditional aggregation:

```
select to_char(date_time, 'MM-DD-YYYY') as "Shipment Date", count(*) as "TOTAL Items",
       sum(case when i.ordertype = 'ORDER' then 1 else 0 end) as NumOrders,
       sum(case when i.ordertype = 'INVENTORY' then 1 else 0 end) as NumInventory
from item_status_log il join
     items i
     on il.itemid = i.itemid
where old_status = 'ONORDER' 
group by "Shipment Date" 
order by "Shipment Date" desc;
```

Comment: perfect! i had to add an inner join since ordertype is in the items table, but you got me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, I wanted to COUNT DISTINCT conditionally, so used something like: COUNT (
  DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.orderType = 'ORDER'
  THEN order_ref_no ELSE NULL END) AS numOrders...

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select to_char(date_time, 'MM-DD-YYYY') as "Shipment Date",
       count(*) as "TOTAL Items",
       sum(case when ordertype = 'INVENTORY' then 1 else 0 end) as "Inventory",
       sum(case when ordertype = 'ORDER' then 1 else 0 end) as "Ordered"
  from item_status_log i
 where old_status = 'ONORDER'
 group by "Shipment Date"
 order by "Shipment Date" desc
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Postgres 11), casting data types confused Postgres.

The outer query had a `character varying` date column, which I was casting to `date` in the query. That confused Postgres and it would refuse to refer to that grouped date column from a subquery. I had to change the data type of the grouped column in the table itself and use that in the query, which worked fine.

Before:

```
SELECT
     outer_tbl.my_varchar_date::date,
     :
     (SELECT .. FROM inner_table
      WHERE outer_tbl.my_varchar_date::date >= inner_tbl.some_date)
FROM
     outer_tbl
GROUP BY outer_tbl.my_varchar_date::date;
```

After:

```
SELECT
     outer_tbl.my_date_date,
     :
     (SELECT .. FROM inner_table
      WHERE outer_tbl.my_date_date >= inner_tbl.some_date)
FROM
     outer_tbl
GROUP BY outer_tbl.my_date_date;
```

Comment: Similar, but in my case the issue was casting from `timestamptz::date`. Changing the source table's datatype wasn't an option for me, so I used a Common Table Expression (i.e. a `WITH` declaration) to perform the casting up-front, at query time, and this solved it.